# Read file upon .bashrc startup, based on date

Tags: shell, scripting

I'd like to put a script in my startup that reads a line from a text file, and echoes this to the screen. However, I'd like a different line from the file based on what day of the month it is.

Thus if it's the 3rd of the month, read line 3. If it's 22nd, read the 22nd line.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed` and `date`:

```bash
sed -n "$(date +'%e')p" textfile.txt
```

`date +'%e'` gives you the day of the month and this is used as an index for the line `sed` should print `p`.

/edit: Worked in feedback from the comments.

Comment: just in case check it work for 9, e.g. ` sed "09p" ` should print  line number 9.

Comment: `date +%e` will get you a not-zero-but-blank prefixed digit when the day of the month is less than 10. As always, see `strftime(3)` for details.

Comment: Doesn't work for me without the `-n` option. `sed -n "$(date +'%e')p" textfile.txt`